# Make pair from row/column data of Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make pairs from below like dataframe from python
What I'd like to do is make pairs with row and column like:
(1,a), (4,c), (6,c), (3,d), (2,f), (4,f), (6,f), (6,g)

Is there any way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "make pairs"? Are these random pairs? How many pairs? etc.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience but could you see the image by clicking "Example"

Comment: paste the data as text & not as pictures

Comment: Still unclear on what you want exactly. Could you explain what you are starting with and what you expect to get?

Comment: i think OP wants the column & rows names where 1 is present as a `tuple`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a data frame like this:

```
     a   b   c    d   e    f    g
1  1.0 NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN
3  NaN NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN  1.0
```

You can use [`stack` against axis 1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get

```
s = df.stack()
```

```
1  a    1.0
2  f    1.0
3  d    1.0
   g    1.0
dtype: float64
```

And a simple `to_list()` gives

```
>>> s.index.to_list()

[(1, 'a'), (2, 'f'), (3, 'd'), (3, 'g')]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Data**:

```
     a   b   c    d   e    f   g
1  1.0 NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN
3  NaN NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN
4  NaN NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN
```

**Option 1**: You can use `np.where`:

```
rows, cols = np.where(df.eq(1))
[*zip(df.index[rows], df.columns[cols])]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'f'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'd'), (4, 'f')]
```

**Option 2**:

```
df.stack().index.values
```

Output:

```
array([(1, 'a'), (2, 'f'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'd'), (4, 'f')], dtype=object)
```